# Google Cloud VM when sudoing asks for password

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform, sudo

I've been working with a Google Cloud debian VM and had no problem at all doing super user tasks using sudo (sudo was not asking for password).

Today I connected via SSH as usual and when I try to ***sudo something*** it started asking for password:

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for -----:
```

According to the documentation it should not ask for password as is already SSL Key authenticated connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by myself. I post the steps i've followed for anyone who has a similar problem:

1. **Deleted the VM** instance preserving the disk.
2. Created **new VM instance** for recovering pruposes.
3. **Attached the old VM disk** to the new instance
4. Mounted into /mnt/

   ```
   # mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
   ```
5. Change root to mounted partition

   ```
   # chroot /mnt/
   ```
6. Now **edit the sudoers file and the user password and group** as needed
7. Unmount the disk

   ```
   # umount /dev/sdb1
   ```
8. deattach the disk, delete the recovery instance, and **recreate the old VM with the same disk**

Comment: I don't understand, I have the same problem, and I have created recovery instance like you describe, and mount the disk ... but what needs to be changed in sudoers file? Everything looks fine

Comment: you should have a line like this in sudoers: 
    your-username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Answer (score 6):

Today I had the same problem with CentOS 8.x VM. After some testing I found a more simple solution. The group "google-sudoers" is allowed to sudo in /etc/sudoers.d/google_sudoers file, so, to fix the problem and make it permanent add your user to "google-sudoers" group with the next steps:

1. SSH to your VM from GCP's web console
2. Run `sudo usermod -a -G google-sudoers USER` to add your USER to google-sudoers group
3. Close your current SSH session and open a new one
4. Test that everything works ok

You should be able to run sudo commands or gain root again.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this, one solution is open the ssh terminal on the web browser from GCP console. You can give a try on this. This is because of SSH key related configuration on Google Clound Engine

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem right now, under the same circumstances you did (suddenly asking about the password) but I just logged out (closed the ssh session) and logged back in and it worked.