# GCE sudo asking for password

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, sudo

My GCE instance has suddenly started asking for a password when using sudo, no idea what has changed

Like this:
[Google Cloud VM when sudoing asks for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266975/google-cloud-vm-when-sudoing-asks-for-password)

However I really don't want to use the provided solution of deleting and recreating my instance, there must be a simple way to prevent sudo asking for a password?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ah OK, I was being stupid.
My SSH keys had an expiry date and that was why sudo was asking for a password.
Just change expiry date and everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do **something** like [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470383/how-to-avoid-being-prompted-for-a-password-by-sudo#470466)

Don't forget to make a copy of this file before editing and to try the connection in a private tab to test asap after update.

Having to type a password after a sudo seems to be a good security to have, so do it at your own risks.

Comment: I can't use sudo because there isn't a password to authenticate with

Comment: My bad I misunderstood.
I have no idea why, sorry :(